# How do ports work through NAT?

Tags: networking, router, nat

i can't quite word it in the tutorial, but this is what I'm talking about
Public IP: 10.0.0.1
Private IPs 192.168.0.1, 192.168.0.2 and 192.168.0.3 connect to argos.com google.com and ebay.com through the same port, the router recieves these packets and converts their addresses to the routers public address, The server processes this information and sends packets back to 10.0.0.1, But now we have three different destinations with then address and port of 10.0.0.1:80, How does the NAT work from there? Would the same packet be sent to all three computers?

Comment: The src port doesn't need to be the same as the dst port.

Comment: Yes, You're right, it was just for simplicities sake @hardillb

Answer (score 2):

Router's NAT table contains

- Destination IP:port (where the packet is sent to, i.e., for example, `google.com:80`)
- Used WAN IP:port (10.0.0.1:12354, for this connection, for example)
- Local client IP:port (192.168.0.1:1234, for example)

When router recieves the packet from google.com:80 to 10.0.0.1:12345, it knows that this packet must be transferred back to 192.168.0.1:1234.

If two inner clients want to access the same external node google.com:80 then router will use different WAN ports for these connections (for example, 12345 and 12346) - so the parameters of the answer is full enough to understand, what inner client the answer packet must be transferred to.

PS. In most cases router has only one external (WAN) address, but it is not a dogma.

Answer (score 1):

Internally, the router assigns a new and unique port to the connection in a [table called NAT](http://www.firewall.cx/networking-topics/network-address-translation-nat/228-nat-table.html). This way, when the response comes back, it identifies the internal port which it formerly assigned and can then know to which source forward the return packet. Example:

1. Host 192.168.0.1 opens https://google.com (port 443)
2. Request reaches router and internally assigns a new port for the *outgoing* request (example, 45678).
3. Google sees the request like coming from your_public_ip:45678 to google.com:443.
4. Google sends the answer to your_public_ip:45678.
5. Your router knows this port was mapped to the client 192.168.0.1, and sends the answer back.

Comment: Could a server have a different external and internal port too?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand what you mean. When you make a TCP request from your server, a *local* port is generated as well (usually a high one), which might be different from the one that your router generates in its NAT table. But this server's source port will allow your router to know where to forward upcoming packets using its NAT table.

Comment: Thanks, im asking if a server could perhaps have the external port of 54321, But the internal port as 12345, If for example, The server manually set the external and internal ports

Comment: What do you mean by "internal" and "external" ports?

Comment: By the looks of it the original IP in the LAN and the transferred ip in the WAN (internal and external) can be manually set in the port forwarding area of routers.